# Integrate Django Oauth Toolkit urls correctly

Tags: django, django-oauth

I followed the instructions from the official django-oauth toolkit doc (https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_02.html) and included all oauth-toolkit urls manually to prevent users from creating applications.

In my root urls.py i added the following line to the url patterns, as showed in the tutorial:

```
url(r'^o/', include(oauth2_endpoint_views, namespace="oauth2_provider")),
```

I used the `include` from `django.conf.url` package.

Now when i start the server, it says

"Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead."

when i add a `name` attribute to the url-command like this:

```
url(r'^o/', include(oauth2_endpoint_views, namespace="oauth2_provider"), name="oauth2_provider"),
```

the server starts up, but when i try to visit "localhost/o/applications" it says "NoReverseMatch: 'oauth2_provider' is not a registered namespace"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @ishitasharma where exactly should i do that? oauth2_endpoint_views is just an array of all oauth2_provider routes i want to make available...

Comment: try to use the this answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 url(r'^o/', include(('oauth2_provider.urls', 'oauth2_provider_app', ), namespace='oauth2_provider'), ),
```

Refer [oauth2_provider](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/issues/553)